# Angular: There is a way to get Form value different that displayed?

Tags: angular, forms

In Angular, there is a way to get Form value different that displayed?

For instance, you implement an Angular FormInput that display the value number "3,567.56 $" to user.

```
<input formInputControl="price" money>
```

I would like that the directive `money` return the value "3567.56" when the `form.get('price').value` of the FormGroup() is called.

I tryed to implement the [Control Value Accessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) but I not found solution to transform the value between that the displayed and that I would like.

> EDIT 1

I would like to implement a directive that normalize the value for computations in the app and provide a readable value to user (UX).

Comment: form.get().value return the value of the field. It's impossible to return 3567.56 if the field value is 123 (for example). Can you explain your requirement ? It's a weird use case tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of search and test, I found the solution.

In the directive, in `@HostListener('input', ['$event'])`, I implemented the call `this.onChange(this.normalizeValue(el.value))`.

The call to [onChange](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor#registeronchange) allow to update the value after a normalization.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a custom pipe:

**TS:**

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    'price': [null]
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <input type="text" formControlName="price" [value]="myForm.get('price').value | myPipe">
</form>
```

**PIPE:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myPipe'
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any): any {
        // example:
        return value ? value.replace('$', '') + '$' : null;
    }
}
```